# SQL query , How to select a generated field in GROUP BY

Tags: sql, oracle10g

I am trying to select two things customer_id and segment(based on some logic) which require both of them to be in GROUP BY

I tried using without alias(like giving CASE...END) but it failed as there is MAX in a a GROUP BY fieldname . If I chop off MAX then also it fails to compile .

What should I do to take care off this ?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why you need "Group by" clause when you are already applying distinct. I strongly believe removing "Group by" clause from your query will give you the result you expect.

Comment: It does not work. I get this error Statement 2 is not valid. ORA-00937: not a single-group group function

Comment: he/she can't remove the `group by` because of the aggregate function in the select list.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the `MAX()` function will mis-behave if `GROUP BY` is removed.  `DISTINCT` may be redundant here (and even in the general case)

Answer (score 0):

I believe this was working for me in an SQL Fiddle:

```
alter session enable parallel query;

SELECT
  t1.CUSTOMER_ID AS CUSTOMER_ID,
  MAX(CASE WHEN t2.event_date=t1.event_date  -- MAX is moved all the way outside
           THEN 'SweepAcquired' 
           ELSE 'NonSweepAcquired'
           END) AS SEGMENT
FROM dsi t1, transaction t2
WHERE t1.CUSTOMER_ID=t2.CUSTOMER_ID(+)
AND t1.MARKETPLACE_ID = '1'
AND lower(t2.event_type(+))='like'
AND lower(t2.SOURCE_TYPE(+))='sweepstakes'
AND t2.SOURCE_ID(+) IS NOT NULL
AND lower(t2.SOURCE_ID(+)) <> 'unknown'
AND t2.ENTITY_ID(+)='1'
GROUP BY t1.CUSTOMER_ID, 
         CASE WHEN t2.event_date = t1.event_date
              THEN 1 
              ELSE 0 
              END
ORDER BY t1.CUSTOMER_ID, SEGMENT
;
```

For some reason, `CASE WHEN MAX() CASE WHEN` wasn't working for me.  I also simplified a couple things based on duplication in the `WHERE` clause.

Working fiddle here http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/630d7/46

Comment: I have edited your answer, adding the fiddle link you have created as mentioned in another post.